# Do you make Pulls for encounters that could have happened, but didn't?

Tags: gm-techniques, dread

I've played a couple of Dread games (4/5 players) and usually one player survives. 
In a recent Dread RPG game the GM had us pull multiple times at random moments.

Situation:

We camped for the night and we (as a group) had to pull a total of four times.

Naturally, I asked him about it afterwards.
He said we pulled for every 'random encounter' that could have happened.

I didn't go into it any further but is this allowed?
The manual isn't clear about it but maybe someone else knows.
If not, I'll probably house rule it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Page 29 of the PDF mentions

> Don’t cheat the other players. While you will be playing the role of
>   their adversaries, you are not their enemy. Everyone is in this
>   together, and the players must trust you.

and

> Don’t monopolize the story. Ask the other players about their
>   characters and what they are up to. Make sure that they are active
>   participants. More than that, make sure they are the driving force in
>   the story. This can only be accomplished if they are doing things.

Page 30 of the PDF mentions

> Don’t be unreasonable. If players have good explanations for why they
>   shouldn’t have to make as many pulls, listen to them.

The context of this latter quote is about character motivation, but this might apply in your game.

Most important, this quote from page 30:

> So any time the game hits a lull, you can give it a kick start by
>   requiring a pull. Of course, this pull must represent something
>   happening in the game.

Now, your GM might or might not have given you enough hints about what happened. I've certainly had games where I thought I was relaying enough information about the environment, only to have players tell me they wanted to do stuff that was physically impossible with the situation as I had narrated. But if you're correct, I'd say no, your narrator did not tell a good Dread story. He didn't make you pull based on something happening in-game, he didn't make you the protagonists at those points of the story, and you didn't get to explain why you shouldn't have had to pull.

Comment: Thank you, that last quote was exaclty what I was looking for.